# how can I set the css box-shadow property to overlap images?

Tags: html, css, shadow, overlap, box-shadow

I am trying to get the box-shadow effect of the navbar to overlap the image.
This is the example website: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-cannon-8c3kh?file=/public/index.html 
It works fine over text but not images.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I see it in your Demo, the box shadow is perfectly working. The opacity (.15) is a little low, though. Maybe you just do not see the shadow because it's very light and has a very low opacity?

Comment: Have you compared it in several browsers? Because it worked for me, as far as I could tell. Screenshots of the issue would be nice also.

Comment: Just change the parameters - it is clearly seen on the screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ7Hk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the image box-shadow is working. And yes the problem is in opacity most probably.

[box-shadow]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOkSP.png

Comment: navBarHeader is not supposed to have a shadow. The only shadow is attached to the navBar class. So what i'm trying to do is to assign box-shadow property to the navigation bar which is fixed allowing the rest of the website content to scroll

Comment: see my second answer and screen.